# Using HERE API credentials for Batch Geocoding?

Tags: geocoding, web-service, here-maps

I have been trying to create my own geocoder using the HERE API to handle geocoding jobs. I have the HERE api I'D, code, and key. I have reviewed much of their developer information and am still confused about how to use the developer material to geocode batches of addresses. Some material appears as though I click on a url (such as https://batch.geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/jobs) while the documentation seems show chunks of script.

How do I use my HERE API credentials to actually geocode multiple addresses?

Do I need to create a website using HTML so that I can create a place or web portal to upload my data as in the example of Batchgeo or other web-based geocoders?

That was what I was attempting initially.

How do I use the HERE developer examples and materials to actually geocode a list of multiple street addresses in the U.S. and receive either a geocoded file (.shp or GeoJSON) that I can use in a map?

[image: Here is part of the HERE developer material that I am confused by. What do I do with this? Place it somewhere?]

Comment: Just need job with a list of addresses (formatted correctly) https://developer.here.com/documentation/batch-geocoder/topics/submit-batch-request.html